# prove inequality $| f(x) - f(y) | < 1/16$

Tags: analysis, inequality

$f: [ 4, + \infty) \to \mathbb R$

$f(x)= 1/Ax$

Prove:  $| f(x) - f(y) | \le 1/16 $

I don't know what to do ...
I have no idea... Please help. I have very important test...

Comment: What is the condition on $A$ ?

Comment: If it is a lipschitz condition ... A = 4

Comment: Is it $1/(Ax)$ or $(1/A)x$?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $A \ge 8$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| = \left|\dfrac{1}{Ax}-\dfrac{1}{Ay}\right| = \dfrac{|x-y|}{Axy} \le \dfrac{|x|+|y|}{xyA} = \dfrac{1}{A}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}\right) \le \dfrac{1}{A}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{4}\right) =\dfrac{1}{2A} \le \dfrac{1}{16}$, as claimed.

Comment: Can easily be improved to $A \ge 4$, since $|f(x)-f(y)| < \frac1A\max(\frac1x, \frac1y)$ as $f$ is positive.